# Why is mongoose findOneAndUpdate method producing http header sent error?

Tags: mongoose

When I try to send a `patch request` with an `id` that does not exist in my database, an error is generated(given below), at the same time I get a response message(given below) in the postman app. The `patch request` uses the `updateTask`, which is producing the error. I think this method is sending the response method twice and thus causing the error. However, I could not find a way to solve it.

```js
    const updateTask = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const { id: taskId } = req.params;
        const task = await Task.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: taskId }, req.body, {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true,
        }).exec();
        if (!task) {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with id: ${taskId}` });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ task });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
      }
    };
```

The error I am getting,

```
    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Dipto\Desktop\Webdev\node-express-johnsmilga\03-task-manager\starter\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)      
        at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Dipto\Desktop\Webdev\node-express-johnsmilga\03-task-manager\starter\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)        
        at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Dipto\Desktop\Webdev\node-express-johnsmilga\03-task-manager\starter\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)        
        at updateTask (C:\Users\Dipto\Desktop\Webdev\node-express-johnsmilga\03-task-manager\starter\controllers\tasks.js:110:21)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
    }
```

The response to the postman app,

```json
    {
        "msg": "No task with id: 61f1a10a0731586c3c9f3433"
    }
```

Comment: just try adding `return` before `res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No task with id: ${taskId}' });` as in `return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No task with id: ${taskId}' });`

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I added `return`. I used the same code with `findOneAndDelete`, but did not face this error. Also it works, if I just change the logic a little and change the position of response messages like so. 
`if (task) {
res.status(200).json({ task }); }
res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No task with id: ${taskId}' });
 `
Strange behavior.!!! Do you know why it behaving like that?

Comment: If you don't `return`, the code carries on executing whatever is past your if block. So if this condition is true `if (!task) {`, you send 2 responses. The first one, inside the if block, sends the headers. The second, below the if block, also sends the headers. And that's where the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what `return` does to the code. But I could not get, why it behaves different in some situation. Like I said It worked perfectly with `findOneAndDelete`. But now with `findOneAndUpdate`, it causing the error. And again changing the `if` logic also make it work without error. Could you explain it, why it happens?